# Interpretation of уже

Tags: словоупотребление

In my favorite Russian podcast, [russianmypassion.com](http://www.russianmypassion.com), the speaker said the following:

> Мы говорим *баян*, когда кто-то пытается рассказать нам какую-то старую,
>   несмешную (ну, **уже** несмешную) шутку.

I'm having a hard time understanding the intended meaning of the parenthetical statement with **уже**. Could someone explain this usage?

Comment: It may be useful: `ещё/пока` is opposite in meaning to `уже` when we are talking about the events with respect to the present time. ещё/пока не смешно - уже не смешно; ещё/пока не посмотрел - уже не посмотрю (a new movie at the cinema); он ещё не ходит (child in arms) - он уже не ходит (very old man).

Answer (score 5):

The whole sentence can be translated as:

> We say "баян", when someone tries to tell us an old, not funny (well, not funny **anymore**) joke.

The joke may have been funny long time ago, when it first appeared, but now it is old, everyone knows it, and nobody laughs at it anymore.

Comment: Aha, so it's the normal usage of уже не. I thought it was something like "well, obviously not funny" but maybe I overthought it :) Thank you for your explanation!